# Why isn't it possible for Imagick class to convert pdf files to image files?

Tags: php, image, pdf, imagick

I would like to convert a pdf file to images in PHP.

I have got some exception like this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException: UnableToOpenBlob './sample.pdf': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3533 in D:\Task\Clients\James\toImage\toImage.php:4 Stack trace: #0 D:\Task\Clients\James\toImage\toImage.php(4): Imagick->readImage('./sample.pdf') #1 {main} thrown in D:\Task\Clients\James\toImage\toImage.php on line 4

I wrote some code like as follows.

```
<?php
    $pdf_url = ('./sample.pdf');
    $imagick = new Imagick();
    $imagick->readImage($pdf_url);
    $imagick->resizeImage( 200, 200, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 0);
    $imagick->setImageFormat( "png" );
    $imagick->writeImage('pdfAsImage.png');
```

Please help me!

Comment: "_No such file or directory_" sounds like the file doesn't exist

Comment: Why `./sample.pdf`? What's wrong with `sample.pdf`?

Comment: Could you possibly show what's in $pdf_url value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I have ever used before.
Use the full path to the image, for example:

```
$image = new Imagick($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/pdfs/sample.pdf');
```

It should work like a charm!!!